# How to output Specs2 result to a file

Tags: scala, akka, specifications, scalatest, specs2

I have code something like this

```
class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {
  "This is a specification for the 'Hello world' string".txt

  "The 'Hello world' string should" >> {
    "contain 11 characters" >> {
      "Hello world" must haveSize(11)
    }
```

While I run this test I prints result in console, I want results in separate file(other file) not in console what I do?

Comment: Redirect console output to a file?

Comment: xml results are also available in the junit format by passing the junitxml argument on the command line.